# How to call python function using process builder

Tags: java, python

I want to call a function from a python file and its working properly if I run the command through terminal.
Name of my python file is `test.py`:

I went to directory where my python file is kept and run this command:

```
python -c 'from test import *;
print myPythonClass().jpg2bmp("/home/vaishali/Desktop/images/27Dresses_D.jpg")'
```

But I want to run this command through Java.
I tried:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python -c 'from test import *;
print myPythonClass().jpg2bmp(\"/home/Desktop/images/27Dresses_D.jpg\")'");
```

but its not working may be some minor mistake.
Even I want to pass filename as argument. How can this be done?
If you know something related to this then pls share

Comment: "its not working" - what do you mean by this?  What is the output you are getting?

Comment: M not getting any output

Comment: When you say you are "not getting any output", does this mean your Java program hangs, or is it just that the output image isn't being written?  Are you waiting for the process to exit, by calling `proc.waitFor()`?  Are you reading from the standard output and standard error of the process?